# Converting a font character number into a string

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I'd like to draw a specific character number in a font  using NSString's drawAtPoint() routine.

To do this I've been casting the integer value of the specific character into an NSString:

```
int characterNumber = 150; //character 150 in a particular font

NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:(const unichar*)&characterNumber length:1];
```

This works if the character number is less than 128. If the characterNumber is greater than that (my font contains 200+ characters) then no character prints. If the character number is 150, and I change the string length to 2, then the wrong character from the font prints.

Is this an encoding issue?

Comment: More information is needed. Can you edit the question and give the declaration of `characterNumber`, how it is assigned a value, what that value is/represents, etc.? With that someone might be able to help you.

Comment: characterNumber is the ASCII value of the character in question, so if I were trying to draw character at position 100 in the font, I'd try to turn 100 into a one character string, set the font and draw that string to the screen.

Comment: You should at least declare `characterNumber` as a `unichar` if you are using Unicode (and not use a cast) - an `int` is at least 32-bits, a `unichar` is 16-bits. However a font with 200 glyphs doesn't mean those glyphs occupy contiguous positions, e.g. 0-199. Add more details to your question and maybe someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be:

unichar characterNumber = 150; //character 150 in a particular font

NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&characterNumber length:1];

Comment: You're right, that's a typo. I'm passing the address of an int and casting it to unichar*.  I'll fix my code excerpt above.

Comment: I just ran a short text with 223 as the incoming characterNumber. It's properly converted to U+00df. The weird part is that [NSString drawAtPoint] doesn't render that symbol correctly.

Comment: Characters seem to work up until character 126. Character 127 doesn't show in the drawAtPoint call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, it turned out, is that character 0x007F (127) is the DEL character, and is unprintable.

Other issues I had with my custom font turned out to be issues of encoding, which had to be worked out in Fontographer, rather than in NSString.